# How to disable the timeout setsockopt() has set?

Tags: sockets, udp, setsockopt, recvfrom, berkeley-sockets

In the program I am developing,  I've set a timeout using `setsockopt()` in order to prevent `recvfrom()` from blocking indefinitely. How can I disable the timeout?

*(I'm on Ubuntu)*

Answer (score 4):

Same way you set it, but with a value of zero instead of a positive value.

As it says in the [*man* page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket).